# Rails rendering file with locals using instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I've just updated to Rails 2.3.11. In an earlier version I could write the following

```
render :file=>'console/users/show.html.erb', :locals => {:@user => @users.first}
```

which no longer works, instead I need to write

```
render :file=>'console/users/show.html.erb', :locals => {:user => @users.first}
```

which means to access the user in the file I would use 'user' but in the file I would like to use the instance variable @user as this same show file is called from the controller and passes @user

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `@user` before calling `render`:

```
@user = @users.first
render :file=>'console/users/show.html.erb'
```

The `:locals` option should only be used if you are passing local variables through.